# Exponentially weighted running mean (moving average) using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, weighted-average

I have been trying to get the exponentially weighted running mean for a series of mean daily outdoor temperatures (`temp_series`), defined as follows:
[image]

I would like to use a value of alpha=0.8 and input a custom period of days.
I have tried using:

```
trm = temp_series.ewm(alpha=0.8).mean()
```

and

```
trm = df_wea_dd.ewm(alpha=0.8, min_periods=30, adjust=False).mean()
```

but the values I obtain are not reliable (I have checked using excel for a period of 30 days). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "reliable"?

Comment: `ewm().mean()` computes running mean over the entire history. what do you mean by *a custom period of days*.

Comment: you should provide a [mcve] to remove as much ambiguity as possible

Comment: @doctorlove it means I am getting results that are significantly different from those I obtain using excel for validation

Comment: @piRSquared you are right, my question could be better framed. I ll provide an example

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this? I am guessing you are trying to calculate tc on CIBSEs model. I have been stuck in the same place. @Andreuccio